# Specify Doctrine2 annotations to describe a complex join

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity A, which I would like to be associated with other entities (also A).

I would typically do this with a joining entity, say B, of the form-

B.leftAssoc = A(1).id
B.rightAssoc = A(2).id

Then I'd join using SQL like:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT *
FROM
  a AS a1,
  a AS a2,
  b
WHERE
  (a1.id = 1234 AND a1.id = b.leftAssoc AND a2.id = b.rightAssoc)
  OR
  (a2.id = 1234 AND a2.id = b.leftAssoc AND a1.id = b.rightAssoc)
```

I'd like to achieve this using Doctrine 2 annotations to specify the tables, and get Symfony to build everything I need.

I know how to do it by manually creating the tables myself and using DQL or QueryBuilder to do it. But really I'd prefer for the entity to know how to get the associations itself.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand you want a self referencing many-to-many relation?

Check this link: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing

If you don't please tell me what you want.